# Overriding lower bounded arguments

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I want to know why java does not allow to override lower bounded generic arguments.

```
public interface NumberConsumer {
    public void accept(Consumer<? super Number> consumer);
}

public interface IntegerConsumer extends NumberConsumer {
    @Override
    public void accept(Consumer<? super Integer> consumer);
}
```

In the example above it is perfectly safe to override method accept since NumberConsumer can take a Consumer of Numbers, Serializables and Objects and IntegerConsumer can take all those and Integers as well.

This is not allowed either, even though is also perfectly safe.

```
public interface IntegerPrinter {
    public void print(List<? extends Integer> list);
}

public interface NumberPrinter extends IntegerPrinter {
    @Override
    public void print(List<? extends Number> list);
}
```

Here NumberPrinter can take `List<? extends Integer>` without any problem.

Finally, some similar case (or opposite) it is allowed in returns.

```
public interface NumberListProducer {
    java.util.List<? extends Number> next();
}

public interface IntegerListProducer extends NumberListProducer {
    @Override
    java.util.List<? extends Integer> next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a generics problem, but how java handles its `overriding` feature.

The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type.

So inheritance of types is allowed in overriding methods only in the return type. An exact matching of types should happen in method arguments.

For example, the following cases throw error.

1. ```
   interface PaterntInterface {
       public void accept(Integer consumer);
   }

   interface ChildInterface extends NumberConsumer {
       @Override
       public void accept(Number consumer);
   }
   ```
2. ```
   interface PaterntInterface {
       public void accept(Number consumer);
   }

   interface ChildInterface extends NumberConsumer {
       @Override
       public void accept(Integer consumer);
   }
   ```

   The following cases compiles properly.
3. ```
   interface PaterntInterface {
       public void accept(Integer consumer);
   }

   interface ChildInterface extends NumberConsumer {
       @Override
       public void accept(Integer consumer);
   }
   ```
4. ```
   interface PaterntInterface {
       public void accept(Number consumer);
   }

   interface ChildInterface extends NumberConsumer {
       @Override
       public void accept(Number consumer);
   }
   ```

Your argument that your 1st case,

```
public interface NumberConsumer {
    public void accept(Consumer<? super Number> consumer);
}

public interface IntegerConsumer extends NumberConsumer {
    @Override
    public void accept(Consumer<? super Integer> consumer);
}
```

should be okay because `Consumer<? super Integer>` is superclass of `Consumer<? super Number>` is not valid, since exact matching of method argument types is needed for overriding. Its the same for your 2nd case.
The 3rd case compiles because `java.util.List<? extends Integer>` is sub-type of `java.util.List<? extends Number>`, and inheritance in return type is allowed in method overriding

Comment: You're right, but it would be nice if you'd explain *why* these are the restrictions

Comment: I agree with @Amit, why after all these years Java hasn't make an improvement on that? is it too dificult for the compiler?. It is obvious that a child class can not take more specific arguments because then it wouldn't be able to handle the super class argument, but why the child can not take less specific arguments being this perfectly safe.

Comment: What i ment with more specific for this example would be Number and up (Number, Serializable, Object, i.e. <? super Number>) and less specific (Integer, Number, Serializable and Object, i.e. <? super Integer>)

Comment: @JoseDaSilva - there are good reasons for this (probably official one, but also plain "logical" reasons as well). I was merely suggesting that there answer is incomplete without reasoning.

Comment: @Amir - Ok, but what are those reasons, and which one is the official one, that is easier not to allow override arguments at all?. I do not see another logical reason this shouldn't be allowed (besides it was probably never consided nor will be, or maybe that is just too difficult, which i personally doubt), IntegerConsumer can be treated exactly like a NumberConsumer.